# ODI SCD2 Undefined to few columns

Tags: etl, oracle-data-integrator

Is there anyway we can keep few columns as undefined in SCD2. Currently i see, undefined columns are null in target. But i want the first insert to happen.

I did un-check update checkbox on that target column but it did nothing.

Images-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TowVe.jpg

~Regards

Comment: But what should happen if the first or last name changes in the source for a same employee_id? It's probably a correction or someone changing name so it should probably be updated in your dimension. If you want to correct it even for the past, you can use Overwrite on Change. If you want to keep an history of such a change, you use Add Row on Change. 
Now if you want to ignore any changes in first or last name, you could try using Overwrite on Change and keep the update checkbox unchecked. Not sure it works but you can give it a try.

Comment: Hi @JeromeFr, I am preparing myself for an upcoming project. So analyzing odi with all scenario. "Overwrite on Change and keep the update checkbox unchecked", i did this but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update SCD IKM for this.
In our project we faced similar situation, and the only solution to this is update the SCD IKM to take "Undefined" columns from Data Model into your INSERT but not consider them for any other task such as not taking them in NOT EXISTS clause within IKM.

Let me know once you try this and face any issues.

Make sure to copy existing IKM as a new "Custom IKM" and change there, just to make sure you don't lose actual code by mistake